# How can I make Windows on my ASUS touch PC more user-friendly?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, touchscreen

I've bought this ASUS Eee touchscreen computer recently.

The main issue with it is that buttons, or e.g. file lists in folder are very small, so it's very very hard to click anything correctly with my fingers, especially with standard XP theme.

I was trying to decrease the screen resolution, but it makes everything look ugly. So I wanted to ask for advice. Maybe there is a Windows theme with large items, e.g. large icons, large file lists in folders, etc.

Is something specially created for touch screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 you can increase the DPI, which should make everything bigger. You might be able to do it in XP, but I'm not sure.

To do it in Windows 7, go to *screen resolution* and there will be "Make text and other items larger or smaller" and choose one of the options.